# count a character in each row and divide it into the number of columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a bunch of genotype files genotype-HA1_1, ..., genotype-HA1_27. Rows are SNPs and columns are individuals.Number of individuals (i.e., columns) differs in each genotype file.Here are 2 examples of how they look like:

```
head genotype-HA1_1    
A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
C   C   C   C   C   C   C   N   C   C
N   K   K   K   T   K   K   N   G   N
N   A   A   A   R   A   A   A   A   A
Y   Y   T   Y   C   T   Y   T   T   Y
```

and

```
head genotype-HA1_11
A   A   W   A   A   W   A   A   A   N   A
C   C   C   C   C   C   C   N   C   C   C
G   G   K   G   N   K   K   N   G   G   G
A   A   A   A   N   A   A   N   A   A   A
```

I want to count the total number of character "N" for each SNP and divide it to the number of individuals (i.e., columns) in each file over a loop.

my desired output

```
count-genotype-HA1_1
0
0.1
0.3
0.1
0
```

I am using something like this

```
for cfile in genotype-HA1_*; do
awk -F\N '{print NF-1/NF}' "$cfile" > count-"${cfile##*.}"; done
```

part of the code that counts the number of "N" works perfectly fine, I just do not know how to divid it into the number of columns in each file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using N as a field separator, why not use the default whitespaces separator such that `NF` has its conventional interpretation (i.e. the number of columns), and use the return value of `gsub` to count the `N`s?

```
$ awk '{print gsub("N","N")/NF}' genotype-HA1_1 
0
0.1
0.3
0.1
0
```

---

NOTE: `gsub("N","N")` counts occurrences of the character `N` in the record (line), which isn't generally the same as the number of fields that equal `N` (although in your sample input these are the same). If you need the stricter definition, then a KISS approach would be something like:

```
awk '{c = 0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) c += ($i == "N"); print c/NF}' genotype-HA1_1
```